# $\sigma$-field and family of sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the function $f(x)=-4x^{2} + 4x$ let $\mathcal M$ be any $\sigma$-field in $[0,1]$.
Is the family of sets
$\mathcal N= \{f(A): A \in \mathcal M \} $ a $\sigma$-field in $[0,1]$? Why?

Comment: Does it contain $[0,1],\emptyset$? Is it closed under complements? Countable unions? Please tell where exactly you have trouble.

Comment: I am not sure how to understand the function
1) f(∅)=∅? ∅=0 in this function?
2) f(A)∈M X\f(A) = ?
3) ??

Comment: You might want to take a look at the wikipedia entry of [Image (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)).

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what is the solution of the exercise? I know what is an image but I don't understad really good measure theory so I would like to see more examples. It could be pretty helpful for me.

Comment: The answer is no, I have posted below how you can find your own counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you look at the graph of the function, you will see that one can find a nonempty interval $I\subseteq [0,1]$ such that $f(I)\subsetneq[0,1]$, but $f(I^C)=[0,1]$. It follows that you get a counterexample by taking $\mathcal{M}=\Big\{\emptyset,[0,1], I, I^C\Big\}$, since $[0,1]\backslash f(I)$ will not be the forward image of any element of $\mathcal{M}$.